# Adding Char to Char Array in Java

Tags: java

I'm still pretty new to Java so bear with me. I'm making a simple hangman game that takes input from the user. I am trying to append the guessed letter to the knownLetters array but I get a type mismatch. I tried .concat() and got the same type error. Here is where I am now. Any ideas or documentation resources (that a novice can read) would be helpful. Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the comments, everyone! These are very helpful.

```
 public static boolean updateWithGuess(char[] knownLetters,
                                      char guessedLetter,
                                      String word) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(knownLetters));

    int i = 0;
    while(word.indexOf(i, guessedLetter) != -1) {
      i = word.indexOf(i, guessedLetter) + 1;
      knownLetters += guessedLetter;
```

Comment: You can't precisely append to an array. Arrays are fixed-length. You can create a new bigger array if that helps.

Comment: I would recommend using `list`, where you can remove and append items freely

Comment: Rather than using `Array` or `List` use `StringBuilder` and there you can append all the guessed characters. And when ever you want to check whether a `character` is present in the StringBuilder or not, just `convert` `StringBuilder` to String and use `contains()` function.

Comment: I can't comment as I'm a new user myself so I'm writing here.
I believe `+=` wouldn't even compile. This is not the way to append to an Array (apart from the fact that Arrays are fixed size as already mentioned in comments)

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya `StringBuilder` already has `charAt` or `indexOf`, both of which are much more efficient than creating unnecessary strings.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- True, This didn't strike my mind. But yeah we can avoid unnecessary `String`  here.

Comment: For *has the letter been already used?* checks it might be better to store the character's in a set (ex a HashSet) for the amortized lookup cost of O(1). Of course this would mean using additional memory but probably not a big deal in this situation. Performance is likely not a big deal here but as a general rule for the future. It also avoids duplicates, though you would have to watch for capitalization cause it will allow both the upper and lower case variant of a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays in that case is not the best choice because arrays have a fixed size and you cannot dynamically add and remove items, maybe rather choose lists.

If you need a simple introduction, here you are:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-interface-java-examples/

Comment: list take space of o(n) where as this can be done in constant space. Even tho what you suggested is True.

Comment: Surprised no one mentioned sets yet!

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari As you can read here (https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-set-collection-tutorial-and-examples) sets are unordered (which is not very useful for hangman) and does not support duplicate items (which is also not very useful if you want to store words).

Comment: But why can't one manage a set for storing guessed letters and one for required letters? The actual word can be stored separate field. Nothing wrong with that. It's also common to do in games especially when there's a large amount of objects these kinds of redundancies can have performance benefits. Hangman is too simple to see those benefits but it can help with prevent having to handle a whole stack of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned *StringBuilder* and *List* which are a step in the right direction as they dynamic (in number of elements). **However since this question is only concerned with keeping track of each letter that was guessed** a set makes the most sense. One common example is [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Sets do not allow duplicates. However sets will allow both the upper and lower case versions of a character to be present in the set (since they have different values). So you could normalize all the guesses and known letters to either uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: But how do you then want to store a word like "Cheese" because there would then be a duplicate char.

Comment: Just to add using `maps` is a better option. rather than sets. `characters`  are the key and the number of occurrences is the `value` and yet it's in constant time in average cases.

Comment: This is for only checking  *has the letter been already used?* (what the snipping of code is dealing with). It's quite common to keep redundant data in games especially when there is a large scale of objects. You make use of the benefits of different data structures. For hangman performance isn't too important but it will likely lead to less logical errors and complicated conditional statements. Map would not be useful here as we only care about whether a  letter has been guessed or not (quantity has no benefit).